# Using Javascript to toggle an overlay on and off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div called "navbar_menu". When clicked I want the div "nav_overlay" to fade in and then when clicked again, I want it to fade back to not being visible.

At the moment I have set the div 'nav_overlay" to 'display: none' and then using the following javascript, it shows itself when "navbar_menu" is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".navbar_menu").click(function(){
    $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
      $("#nav_overlay").fadeTo("fast", 0.8);
  });
});
```

The tag "nav ul" is just a menu that is sliding when "navbar_menu" is clicked. The point is to have an overlay covering the content when the menu slides out and then when the menu slides in again, the overlay disappears.

I'm thinking that I need an if statement testing whether the div is visible or not? I'm just wonering if there is anyone who can help with the best solution for this.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Could you post the corresponding HTML and (even better) put it all together in a JSFiddle?

Comment: Sorry, here is a link ti jsfiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Forresty/un2fpuy4/2/ Excuse the letter 'A'..that is replaced by a symbol font. I'm trying to replace the 'A' with 'B' on click too...and then have it switch back again. Any help with that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$("#nav_overlay").fadeToggle()
```

See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) for the options.

PS: I assuming that the overlay has necessary styles to cover the whole page with position: fixed or something.

Comment: Thanks. I have created an example on jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Forresty/un2fpuy4/2/ Excuse the letter 'A'..that is replaced by a symbol font. I'm trying to replace the 'A' with 'B' on click too...and then have it switch back again. Any help with that would also be appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/un2fpuy4/7/ is the most that can be done if you really want to use the pseudo element approach. Otherwise, you can just change the textContent of the anchor using JS.

Comment: Thanks very much. I had a go using the .text method in jquery as can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/Forresty/un2fpuy4/9/. Is this approach better than the pseudo method?

Comment: `$(".menu_icon").text() === "A" ? $(".menu_icon").text("B") : $(".menu_icon").text("A");` I ended up using this which seems to work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $('#your-element').is(":visible") ){
    // #your-element is visible.
} else {
    // #your-element is not visible
}
```

That should test if something is visible or not but a link or jsfiddle to your html as well would be helpful.

Comment: Here is a link to an example I done on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Forresty/un2fpuy4/2/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming CSS class 'showing' only makes the element appear. You can use the .toggle function to make it hide and reappear on its own.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/

```
// Will automatically hide/display element
$("nav ul").toggle();

// Same as toggle but with fade effect

$("#nav_overlay").fadeToggle("fast");
```

Comment: The class 'showing' doesn't effect the overlay. I want the overlay to be invisible initially, so I've set it to "display: none". I just want to toggle it on and off on click of "navbar_menu". I've tried what you suggested however it doesn't seem to be toggling on and off. It toggles on and then stays on.